# What is the type of this function argument?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How can i write  a type validation for my second method (i m struggling with the argument **v** as it need's to inherit it's type from values in the Array

`lo.foreEach = ([1,{},true],(v,i,list))=>{/** some code **/}`

do i have to use generics ? i have no idea how to do it.

2nd question  what is the difference between using **Array`<mixed>` and Array`<Any>`**

```
//@flow
type loObjectT = {
  push: (Array<mixed>, mixed) => void,
                             //HERE
  forEach: (Array<mixed>, (v:'****',i:number,list:Array) => void) => void,
};
const lo: loObjectT = {};
lo.push = function (target, filler) {
  if (Array.isArray(target)) {
    target[target.length] = filler;
  }
  throw new Error("i accept only 'Array'");
};
lo.forEach = function (target, callback) {
  if (Array.isArray(target)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
      callback(target[i], i, target);
    }
  }
  throw new Error("i accept 'Array' & 'Set");
};
```

Please can u help me ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `v` type is `target[i]` type.

Comment: How to write @ask4you in typescript or flow please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With typescript: (Note that `mixed` is not a TypeScript type and is the same as `any`)

```js
type loObjectT = {
  push: (target: any[],filler: any) => void,
  forEach: (target: any[],callback: (v:any,i:number,list: any[]) => void) => void,
};

const lo: loObjectT = {
  push:function (target, filler) {
    if (!Array.isArray(target)) throw new Error("i accept only 'Array'");
    target.push(filler)
  },
  forEach: function (target, callback) {
    if (!Array.isArray(target)) throw new Error("i accept 'Array' & 'Set");
    for (let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
      callback(target[i], i, target);
    }
  }
}
```

Also avoid using `any` type. There's no point of using TypeScript if there's no type checking.

Anyway I don't see the point of over-coding. You already have those built-in functions with javascript:

```
const myArray: any[] = []

// Push whatever to array
myArray.push("whatever")
myArray.push({whatever:"whatever"})

// For each position of the array run a callback
myArray.forEach((myArrayPosition,index) => {
  // Your callback code
})
```

Comment: I'm new to type system that is why i'm reinventing the wheel, so i can learn how to use  flow and ts

Comment: Thank you any way , i appreciate your answer !